# Is it possible to implement custom components for Eclipse XML Editor?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We develop a business webframework which is based on complex XML structures. Especially our fullqualified IDs add very much noise to the XML model. We would like to reduce and separate different IDs with a visual editor enhancement for Eclipse.

We have a simple approach where Eclipse should hide those complex IDs and mark them given to their type. We have IDs which refer different types so we could color the buttons in this mockup differently and have a nice view of those reduced IDs.

We already have an own XML Editor with auto completion support for IDs which are shared across files. It would be great when we were able to implement this concept idea.

The "button" shall expand to their complex ID on click or hover. The second mock image shows the expanded state, the first the collapsed state.

[image: Mock for rich editor example]

Are there any ideas, if this is even possible to achieve in Eclipse RCP? Where to start with this idea? Maybe this example is a little bit contrived. We want to expand this functionality and have much more ideas for those "buttons".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to implement your own Eclipse XML editor using an Eclipse plug-in.  You would extend any of the existing Eclipse text editors.

It is possible to get the source code for the Eclipse XML editor, and extend that source code to meet your needs.  This would also be deployed as an Eclipse plug-in.

I don't think it's possible to add functionality to the Eclipse XML editor using Eclipse extensions.

Comment: Not that kind of functionality, anyway.  Aside from line folding, there's little in place to *not* show portions of the file's source.